# angular 4 error handling 500

Tags: angular, error-handling

I build angular 4 and asp.net project.
I'm trying to figure out why I'm still see the error in the console, even I did error handling. 
this is the error I got in the console when i insert name that not exist in data base.

```
GET http://localhost:53842/api/queriestest/asdasdas 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

filter function in component

```
filter(name: string) {
    console.log(name);
    this.serviceQueries.filterQueries(name)
        .subscribe(
        (data: Response) => {
            this.listQueries = data.json();
        },
        (error: AppError) => {
            if (error instanceof BadInputError) {
                alert('this post has already has been deleted')
            }
            else {
                alert('An unexpected error occured');

            }
        }



    );
```

ServicesQueries.ts ( BadInputError and AppError are my own classes I build)

```
 filterQueries(name: string) {
    console.log(`my name is ${name}`);
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:53842/api/queriestest/' + name)
        .catch((error: Response) => {
            console.log("ee");
            if (error.status === 500) {
                return Observable.throw(new BadInputError(error.json()));
            }
            return Observable.throw(new AppError(error.json()));
        });
}
```

QueriesTestController.ts

```
    [HttpGet("{name}")]
    public IActionResult filterPerson(string name)
    {
        List<Employee> ilIst = new List<Employee>();
        Employee Emp;
        Emp = _context.Employee.Where(x => x.EmployeeName == name).First();
        ilIst.Add(Emp);
        return Json(ilIst);
    }
```

My question is why I still see the error in console which I don't want to show the user this way,even i handle it. why is that?

Answer (score 0):

> This is your browser's functionality,

Not a part of Angular you can just disable the logs from the browser if you are using chrome there is a new feature added but if not you cannot prevent the error message from being shown.

Comment: yes, but as user experience I cannot do nothing for that?

Comment: No for your own browser you can disable it going into chrome network tab but not for users

Comment: sounds weird. I tried to make like search on sites who not return this error. for example enter input who not exist...

Comment: This is not a case for browser error. This should return null by server and handled appropriately by Angular

Comment: I thought the whole point of error handling is so that the user don't see them?